# Batch extracting from a text file and placing into the middle of another batch file line

Tags: python, html, batch-file

I need a script that will pull the mining wallet address from a txt file that's been pre saved by the user in RVNAddressFM.txt, and to place that taken bit of text into another batch file and replace the address next to .rig with it.

-cmd.bat-

```
cd C:\windows\system32\WindowsEnhancer\Mine\GareBearMiner\KMD
spEeD_uP -a mtp -o -u RSEHBSFEGp9CBCJqXk1Mo6q2CjTxqSHZny.rig0 -p x -l na.luckpool.net:3861  
exit
```

==================================================

everything resides in there below, my entire 0% fee mining platform works to launch 20 coins from one location and add custom miners to launch with the console, but I simply cant figure this temp stuff out in my head and videos don't cover it anywhere..

```
'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsEnhancer\Mine\GareBearMiner'
```

I found this on the internet as the most helpful so far but this is a very new concept to me and I cant quite wrap my head around it to see what I'm doing blatantly wrong with this script i stole

```
    @ECHO OFF
SET InFile=Test.txt
SET OutFile=Output.txt
IF EXIST "%OutFile%" DEL "%OutFile%"
SET TempFile=Temp.txt
IF EXIST "%TempFile%" DEL "%TempFile%"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('FINDSTR /N "wordA" "%InFile%"') DO (
   CALL :RemovePrecedingWordA "%%A"
   FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=:" %%B IN ('ECHO.%%A') DO (
      MORE +%%B "%InFile%"> "%TempFile%"
      FINDSTR /V "wordB" "%TempFile%">> "%OutFile%"
      FOR /F "tokens=*" %%C IN ('FINDSTR "wordB" "%InFile%"') DO (
         CALL :RemoveWordB "%%C"
         IF EXIST "%TempFile%" DEL "%TempFile%"
         GOTO :eof
         )
      )
   )
GOTO :eof
:RemovePrecedingWordA
SET String=%~1
SET String=%String:*wordA =%
ECHO.%String%> "%OutFile%"
GOTO :eof
:RemoveWordB
REM Replace "wordB" with a character that we don't expect in text that we will then use as a delimiter (` in this case)
SET LastLine=%~1
SET LastLine=%LastLine:wordB=`%
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=`" %%A IN ('ECHO.%LastLine%') DO ECHO.%%A>> "%OutFile%"
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: There is only one line in the text file and it looks like `RSEHBSFEGp9CBCJqXk1Mo6q2CjTxqSHZny`?

Comment: Yes that’s called a crypto currency wallet address, next..

Comment: then my answer should work for you. (I hope you remembered to not use an actual address) Btw: the script you showed does something *very* different than the text explains, so I might be completely off-track (my answer is based on your description and I completely ignored the given code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing a hardcoded string in a script is bad practice. Use a parameter instead, or even better, get the string from the textfile directly in that script:

Change your `cmd.bat` to:

```
@echo off
<RVNAddressFM.txt set /p "name="
cd /D "C:\windows\system32\WindowsEnhancer\Mine\GareBearMiner\KMD"
spEeD_uP -a mtp -o -u "%name%.rig0" -p x -l na.luckpool.net:3861  
exit
```

(by the way: `cmd.bat` is a bad choice of name; better think of something different)

You may want to give the full path to `RVNAddressFM.txt` or `cd /d` to the containing folder before.